# Why didn't Tony Stark protect himself from the power of the Infinity Stones?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In Avengers: Endgame Tony Stark sacrifices himself by snapping fingers while wearing all Infinity Stones. He knew that this move would be fatal to him.

On the other hand, the Infinity Stones provide extraordinary power to the wielder. Notably, the [Power stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_Gems#Description)

> At full potential, the Power Gem grants the user omnipotence.

**Couldn't Tony Stark protect himself from the consequences of the snap, by using the power of the Infinity Stones?**

Wouldn't it have been enough to add to his snap-will "... and make it so that I am intact after the snap"

Comment: The quote you bring is unclear in which powers exist in the MCU and which in the comic books - and there are significant differences. You can't assume that a power that manifests in the comic-books is relevant to the MCU too.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan/ I understand that. I am hoping for an in-MCU explanation (something I would have missed in the movies), falling back to a comics-based one (to have anything beyond assumptions)

Comment: This question sounds an awful lot similar to "can God make a rock too heavy for him to lift?" Does omnipotence assume defying logic as well in your book? If I hazard a guess, it would have been too unrealistic for MCU.

Comment: @M.A.R.: I do not find it to be a good analogy. First, God is an abstract concept whom everyone sees as they fit, with a vague understanding of his powers. We could all see Tony Stark in action and knew what he could do.  Then omnipotence has nothing to do with logic, there is nothing to defy. You just can (TM)

Comment: You can ignore the vagueness and different definitions (and I personally don't even see how that actually *doesn't* strengthen my position, other than it's a sensitive topic). Correct me if I'm wrong, but the ultimate line of reasoning is you can ask Infinity Stones anything and they have the power to grant it and whether that power constitutes defying basic logic, no?

Comment: @M.A.R. I thought you were joking with the logic part (thus my answer). Honestly, logic is not the first thing which comes to my mind when watching superhero movies (and this is a good think, this is not math after all).

Comment: The infinity stones are too powerful for a normal human to wield. Just like Star-lord almost died after holding it, but survived thanks to being only half-human, so you have to be powerfu enough to withstand the power of the stones, and only then they could grant you omnipotence and so on

Answer (score 4):

In the MCU, it's established that you need to be a very powerful being to wield the Infinity Gems.

If you remember in Guardians of the Galaxy, all of them had to hold hands to try and harness the energy of the Power Stone. If it was just Quill, he'd have died. That applies to Jane in Thor too, the Aether was killing her.

In Endgame, for a short moment even Thanos, the mighty, holds the powerstone to fight Captain Marvel, but he too had to return it to the Gauntlet.

In fact the Gauntlet has been crafted specifically to host the stones without killing the person wearing it.

The Snap is all the stones being harnessed at once. When Thanos does the Snap in Infinity War it really destroys his one arm and leaves him terribly weak.

When Hulk, who is also pretty strong, Snaps, his arm needs to be put in a sling.

Tony, in spite of his suit, is nowhere as powerful as the other beings who have wielded the stones directly or through the gauntlet. Performing a Snap is far more than he can take. And hence dies from it.

In short, performing a Snap is not like wishing for something from a Genie, you need to be physically powerful enough to endure the action of the Snap.

Answer (score 2):

### In theory, I suppose he could, in an ideal world.

Recall though that it's not just **using** the Stones that caused the damage but rather the first power surge from taking control.

SmartHulk is damaged just by wearing the Gauntlet (as is Tony) and that damage is, apparently, permanent....he's not primarily damaged by snapping...the damage has already happened by then.

Snapping would only have caused *more damage*...

So Tony is, effectively, using his last gasp at life to perform his snap, knowing he's already dead from just taking control of the stones. At that point, it's arguable whether he *could* have snapped himself back to health at that point.

Whether he could wish for multiple things *at the same time* is highly debatable.

We know that Natasha could not be brought back (SmartHulk said he tried) at the same time as the Unsnappening but whether that's a function of the Stones not being able to or it just not being possible is unknown.

Comment: _"he's not damaged by snapping"_ - I'm pretty confident this is incorrect - Thanos is only damaged once he Snaps - there appears to be "two levels" to it, one by taking on the power of the Stones and one by doing such a Snap.

Comment: Perhaps we watched a different film but [his arm seemed pretty damaged](https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/36/590x/avengers-4-thanos-infinity-gauntlet-1019088.jpg?r=1537257785094) - sure most of the damage we see is on the gauntlet but it is clear it damages his arm underneath it.

Comment: Fair...but Thanos was a lot more powerful than Tony and/or Banner....

Comment: Exactly, so if it damaged him when he snapped you sure can bet it damaged Tony too.

Comment: Sure but my point was that that just putting on the Gauntlet is what killed Tony, the snap is his dying act *despite* that. Once he'd taken that damage there was no going back. Whether he could include healing himself as part of the snap is questionable. No else can / could apparently...everything has it's price. I'll edit a little more.

Comment: Do you have evidence that wearing the gauntlet is what killed him? I can't remember that being the case or being confirmed. The no one else is more like "they could do it but if they did Thanos would still win in the end" as far as I know.

Comment: Keep in mind simply *holding* the power stone is enough to vaporize a person who isn’t plotarmoured, the gauntlet is a tool to absorb the energy of all stones to allow it to be wielded..however even that must have a limit, and some if that energy is definitely going to be transferred to the wearer, as we all saw. I’m not sure it was what would have killed tony, since i assume he was smart enough to have designed the energy transfer into his suit should the possibility arise he have to take it, the snap in my opinion was certainly his certain death, and not the last act of an already dead man.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The quote is "he's not primarily damaged by snapping". The primarily is a pretty key word to omit there. That said, there isn't much references to what the stones in the MCU do or require, but one thing that's made clear is that they're not just weapons to be wielded. The Tesseract banishes the Red Skull, but lets others handle it. The Soul Stone requires a sacrifice, and then blocks that sacrifice from being erased. Thanos can destroy ships, moons, create black holes, reverse time, etc. without repercussion. It's the using the stones to destroy the stones that hurts him. ...

Comment: ... so it's safe to stay that certain spells are the ones that have a cost to the user. It appears to be that SmartHulk paid minimal cost to actually bring people back (inferring from he doesn't seem to visibly take significantly MORE damage on the snap), whereas Tony could have paid more to remove certain people. Given the vagueness of what this "cost" is and how much "power" people have, it's pretty impossible to quantify anything. But it at least logically make sense given what we know of the Soul Stone that it demands a cost to manipulate souls.

Comment: Given the cinematic choice to have Thanos with a left-handed gauntlet, and the Avengers with a right-handed one, (left is evil!) I think it would be mildly interesting if they alluded to the side choice being significant to protecting the health of the user :P

Answer (score 1):

### He did. But the suit wasn't built to save him.

AFAIK he built his last suit to wield the stones and to at least act as a bit of "shield" for him so he can snap it without dying. If you compare the Banner snap and Tony snap, you could see Banner struggling to snap the gauntlet, but with Tony, he basically just snapped it before the power of the stones killed him.